# Best way to get all selected checkboxes VALUES in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am looking to get all checkboxes' VALUE which have been selected through jQuery.

Comment: what do you mean by `selected through jquery`?

Comment: Refer this article: http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/get-selected-checkbox-values/

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You want the `:checkbox:checked` selector and `map` to create an array of the values:

```
var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

If your checkboxes have a shared class it would be faster to use that instead, eg. `$('.mycheckboxes:checked')`, or for a common name `$('input[name="Foo"]:checked')`

**- Update -**

If you don't need IE support then you can now make the `map()` call more succinct by using an arrow function:

```
var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get();
```

Comment: works like charm, i would prefer it as comma seperated string...

Comment: .join(',') does it

Comment: I got comma separated values without using .join('). I am using jQuery 1.10.2. And thanks for saving me time and extra lines of unnecessary lines of code, for me it works just perfect.

Comment: sorry to say that but it will always annoys me: `this.value`. Once you've started to use jQuery, so let's `return $(this).val();`

Comment: @vaso123 It's a personal preference as the performance difference is so slight, but I don't see the point creating a jQuery object for a property already available from `this`.

Comment: Not consecvent. A 3rd users come, and starting to implement his own code as he thinkig, let's say add `$` to a jQuery object vairiable, and when a new developer need to maintain the code, he will found `$(this)`, `$this`, `this`, so he need to take time while figure out the puzzle, and refactor this not clean code. But it's your preference...

Comment: Well, code should be made to the best standards, not the lowest simply so inexperienced developers can understand it.