# Last element of an array comes as an 'Array'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have following code to get the values of all checked checkboxes. Surprisingly last element of an array comes as a 'Array'.

```
var selected = [];
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function(){
  selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Even if only one checkbox is checked, it adds extra element in an array.
Array will be like this:

```
selected[0]=Dove
selected[1]=Array
```

What can be the issue with it? I'm unable to find any reason behind this. Can anyone help?

**HTML Code**

```
<ul id='checkboxes' class="list-style1">
 <?php foreach($brands as $row){ ?>
 <span class='checkbox-wrapper' id='<?php echo $brand; ?>'>
 <li><input type='checkbox' value='<?php echo $row['brand']; ?>'>
 <label for='<?php echo $row['brand']; ?>'><?php echo $row['brand']; ?></label>
 </li></span>
 <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you add the html code as well.

Comment: You probably have an input with `name="name[]"`

Comment: Works for me with same code snippet. http://jsfiddle.net/ros2w6ym/1/

Comment: What is `Dove`? Is it a String?

Comment: @GuiImamura It's the first element of an array when I access through `selected[0]`

Comment: Do you sure that your document has an only one element with the id attribute value `checkboxes`?!

Comment: OP that's not an HTML code.

Comment: @sємsєм Yes that's the only element with #checkboxes

Comment: @GuiImamura Sorry, added correct html code

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkedValues = $('#checkboxes  input:checked').map(function() {
return this.value;
}).get();
```

it will return the selected value of the checkbox in array.

[referrence link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766044/best-way-to-get-all-selected-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)