# Ember.js input checkbox in table

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js, input

I have lots of models and show them in tables. When user needs to do something with several models, we need to give him ability to choose rows.

How can I implement it with checkboxes?  Of course I don't want to create special field on my models for every table.

This is simple example.
https://ember-twiddle.com/0b8f429f6ad3e0572438

My tries were:

```
{{input type='checkbox' checked=model.someNotExistedField}}
```

But in this case input just doesnt work.

And:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{action marked model}}  checked={{in-arr record selectedItems}} />
```

In second example I've tried to keep selected ids in an array on context. But id doesnt work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few steps to solving this problem, which you have not shown in your code examples.

1. you dont need to worry about binding a `checked` value on the checkbox.. it can manage its own internal state, and you can take advantage of it when selecting an item... a native `<input>` should be fine

   `<input type="checkbox">`
2. You will need an action (preferably a [closure action](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_closure-actions)) that handles what to do when a record is selected

   `onchange={{action (action "valueHasChanged" item) value="target.checked"}}`
3. You will need an array to store the "selected items"

   `this.selectedItems = [];`

I put together [a twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f6a6b5b91adcd498993c) as one example of how these pieces fit together.

**(This answer should be valid with ember version 1.13.0 and up)**

Comment: Thx u a lot!  
Especially about twiddle =)

Answer (score 0):

I'am guessing your model is an array of rows.
So try adding a chked (boolean) property to the model structure so you now have one for each row and bind it to the respective checkbox.

Comment: The same model could be checked on one table and be not checked on other table. I need some way that with no dependencies on what model we use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766044/best-way-to-get-all-selected-checkboxes-values-in-jquery/19766067#19766067 @user1871941

Answer (score 0):

I finished with such technic:

1. components/action-based-checkbox.hbs

```html
{{#if checked}}
    <input type="checkbox" {{action changed}}  checked="checked" />
{{else}}
    <input type="checkbox" {{action changed}} />
{{/if}}
```

2. In context we have array with selected items, for instance "selectedItems"
3. In context we have an action, that manages array

   ```
     //2 and 3 steps example

     actions:{
       marked(id){
         this.selectedItems.push(id);
         var uniq = this.selectedItems.uniq();

         this.set('selectedItems', uniq);

       },
     selectedItems:[],
   ```

4.next I put the component to my cell

```
{{inputs/action-based-checkbox changed=(action marked record.id) checked=(in-arr record.id selectedItems)}}
```

in-arr my "in_array?" helper, ember 2.3