# How can i select all input that are selected in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can i get all input that are checked in jQuery?

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">sony </input>
<input type="checkbox">samsung </input>
<input type="checkbox"> Other</input>
</div>
```

Comment: `checked` or `cheched` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get all selected checkboxes VALUES in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766044/best-way-to-get-all-selected-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Can Use This Code

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

Comment: This might not work, as the OP is using `type="chechbox"` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** pseudo-selector

```
$(':checked')
```

```js
console.log(
  $(':checked').length
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">sony
  <input type="checkbox">samsung
  <input type="checkbox" checked>Other
</div>
```

---

**FYI :** There are various bugs in your code :

1. There is attribute like `cheched`, the answer is based on `checked` attribute.
2. Input tag is self closing so `</input>` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('input:checked')
```

More info: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" checked="checked"> sony </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist"> samsung </input>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" checked="checked"> Other</input>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 var checkValues = $('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').map(function()
 {
     return $(this).val();
 }).get(); // it will find list of all checked selectboxes
```