# Create a dynamic link based on checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, hyperlink

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

1. Default state of page = no checkboxes ticked, no link shown
2. User ticks one (or more) checkboxes
3. Link appears, dynamically generated from the checkbox values, in the following format: http://example.com/?subject=Products&checked=Blue,Green,Purple (where the selected checkbox values are "Blue", "Green" and "Purple")

Thus far, based on advice from another question ([Using JavaScript to load checkbox Values into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007622/using-javascript-to-load-checkbox-values-into-a-string/40008127)), I've been able to get the values in the proper format (as part of the required url) printed to console.log via a button:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
 var arr = []
 $(":checkbox").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
   arr.push($(this).val())
    }
 })
 var vals = arr.join(",")
 var str = "http://example.com/?subject=Products&" + vals
 console.log(str) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="selected" name="selected" value="Blue" class="products"> Blue<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="selected" name="selected" value="Green" class="products"> Green<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="selected" name="selected" value="Purple" class="products"> Purple
<br>
<button>button</button>
```

However, they're not loading dynamically based on the selected checkboxes (it requires you to press the button in order to generate the url) and the link hasn't been printed to the page for use by visitors (it's stuck in console.log, visible but not usable).

I've been advised that `.change()` might be the way to go here, in terms of generating the link dynamically. Something like: [jQuery checkbox change and click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event/7031408#7031408).

How can I merge the two approaches to achieve the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Note that the duplicated `id="selected"` in your html is not valid. Ids must be unique :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you were on the right track, if I understood your question correctly.  I added the change event on you checkboxes as you suggested.  Try the modified code below.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="Blue" class="products"> Blue<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="Green" class="products"> Green<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="Purple" class="products"> Purple
<br>
<span class="link"></span>
```

JavaScript

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
    var arr = []
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
         arr.push($(this).val())
       }
    })
    var vals = arr.join(",")
    var str = "http://example.com/?subject=Products&checked=" + vals
    console.log(str);

  if (vals.length > 0) {
    $('.link').html($('<a>', {
      href: str,
      text: str
    }));
  } else {
    $('.link').html('');
  }  
})
```

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwKRjy)

Your `button` is no longer being used.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Don't forget to create and add the actual link to the page

Comment: Not the codepen, the link asked for by the OP - `...and the link hasn't been printed to the page`

Comment: Oh!  Thank you!  I missed that part! It has now been added.

Comment: Perfect! Works exactly the way I want it to, including the extra "Hide Again" option I just asked DelightedD0D above! 

Marking as answer :)

P.S. Thanks @nikolay-ermakov for the gentle poke on the link! ;)

Comment: @JonWatson note that this is missing the `checked=` part of the url (so was your original example though)

Comment: @scarabaeus / OP  also, you'll want to ditch the duplicate id's, obviously taken from the OP's example but they are not valid html :)

Comment: Updated with your suggestions, @DelightedD0D.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This would work to give you  a url of

`http://example.com/?subject=Products&checked=Blue,Green,Purple`

(see below for a possibly better way):

```js
$(document).on("change", ".mod-link", function() {
  var arr = []
  $(".mod-link:checked").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
  })
  var vals = arr.join(",")
  var str = "http://example.com/?subject=Products&checked=" + vals;
  var link = arr.length > 0 ? '<a href="'+str+'">Click me</a>': '' ;
  
  $('.link-container').html(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="mod-link" name="selected" value="Blue" class="products">Blue
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="mod-link" name="selected" value="Green" class="products">Green
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="mod-link" name="selected" value="Purple" class="products">Purple
<br>
<div class="link-container"></div>
```

#### However

I would do it a bit different.

I would opt for the following url structure:

`http://example.com/?subject=Products&checked[]=Blue&checked[]=Green&checked[]=Purple`

When that is recieved by PHP, checked will be an array like `['Blue','Green','Purple']` instead of a string like 'Blue,Green,Purple'

```js
$(document).on("change", ".mod-link", function() {
  var arr = []
  $(".mod-link:checked").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
  })
  var vals = 'checked[]=' + arr.join("&checked[]=")
  var str = "http://example.com/?subject=Products&" + vals;
  var link = arr.length > 0 ? '<a href="'+str+'">Click me</a>': '' ;
  
  $('.link-container').html(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="mod-link" name="selected" value="Blue" class="products">Blue
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="mod-link" name="selected" value="Green" class="products">Green
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="mod-link" name="selected" value="Purple" class="products">Purple
<br>
<div class="link-container"></div>
```

Comment: ^^ Perfection! This is exactly what I was looking for! You rock! 

One last thing. Is it possible for the link to disappear again if the checkboxes are all deselected? Not too bothered if not, but it'd be cleaner if it's possible.

Comment: Amazing! Two working options! @scarabaeus got there a different way, but got it perfect, as well. Absolutely brilliant. Thank you! :D

Comment: P.S. The URL structure is a prerequisite of Gravity Forms. Their query strings are all comma separated. But a really good suggestion, thank you!

Comment: is there a way to make the button always display? maybe have it grey before selection then colored when selected?