# dynamic link based on checkbox values => Issue when deselecting the checkbox the url value multiplies

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to generate link on the button when multiple Checkbox is clicked based on the value. I have used the below link and it's working fine and I am able to generate link.

[Create a dynamic link based on checkbox values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008942/create-a-dynamic-link-based-on-checkbox-values)

The issue is that when I select the checkbox for the first time it generates a link to /collections/all/blue+green but when I again select/deselect the different value its duplicates and ADDs the values with old Link → to collections/all/blue+green+blue+green

For Live Issue check on mobile View Click on filter on bottom =>  https://faaya-gifting.myshopify.com/collections/all

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var arr = []
  $(":checkbox").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      arr.push($(this).val())
    }
  })
  var vals = arr.join(",")
  var str = "http://example.com/?subject=Products&checked=" + vals
  console.log(str);

  if (vals.length > 0) {
    $('.link').html($('<a>', {
      href: str,
      text: str
    }));
  } else {
    $('.link').html('');
  }
})
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="Blue" class="products"> Blue<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="Green" class="products"> Green<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="Purple" class="products"> Purple
<br>
<span class="link"></span>
```

For Live Issue check on mobile View Click on filter on bottom => https://faaya-gifting.myshopify.com/collections/all

Comment: Your code seems to be updating your filters fine: https://www.loom.com/share/00909beaa88d47fbb8bda729dd55fac3

Comment: seems to work fine , can you better word your problem .

Comment: @AlgefAlmocera please check on Mobile View Please...

Comment: @MarkeseP can you please check on Mobile View

Comment: @MarkeseP i have added this function on my filter faaya-gifting.myshopify.com/collections/all First time when i check the url is proper and the second time when i check/uncheck the link duplicate faaya-gifting.myshopify.com/collections/all /Blue,Green,Purple,Blue,Green,Purple

Comment: @AnthonyDavid I see it now. Can you provide us what code gets triggered when you click "Apply" on your filter?

Comment: @AlgefAlmocera i have used the javascript [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008942/create-a-dynamic-link-based-on-checkbox-values].

I am not understanding why its Multipling the tags

Comment: @MarkeseP can you plz help?

Comment: @AlgefAlmocera i have added the script please check whether it is write. or should I add any values on `var set = new Set(arr)` or `var vals = [...set]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what's going on now. What's causing the duplicate is actually multiple `checkboxes` having the checked value.

If you run this code in your console, you should see that you have twice of the item checked as its length:

```
// Run this in your browser console
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

For example, if I have `Wood` and `Metal` checked and clicked `Apply`, running the code above gives length of `4` instead of just 2. Meaning, you have a duplicate `checkbox` input for each filter hidden somewhere in your code. I have verified this.

As options, you can:

1. Try to remove the duplicate checkbox input – Best Option; or
2. Add class to narrow down your selector to just one of the `checkbox input containers`.

Here's a screenshare of what's going on: https://www.loom.com/share/2f7880ec3435427a8378050c7bf6a6ea

UPDATED 2020/06/09:
If there's actually no way to modify how your filters are displayed, or add classes to narrow things down, we can opt for an `ad hoc` solution which is to actually, just remove the duplicates:

```
  // get all your values
  var arr = []
  $(":checkbox").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      arr.push($(this).val().toLowerCase())
    }
  })

  // removes duplicates
  var set = new Set(arr)

  // convert to array and join
  var vals = [...set].join(",")
```

Comment: Hey the issue is because I have hidden the section for mobile and made a separate section for Mobile Checkbox. Any idea how to make sure when i click on mobile its doesnt trigger on the desktop section.

if this would work by narrowing down with class can you give me a exampl with my code Please

Comment: Hi @AnthonyDavid, edited my answer and added a solution you can try above. What it does is to simply remove the duplicates instead.

Comment: @AnthonyDavid the unchecking of the selected happens after you already clicked Apply. It happens even before the above fix was provided. I did encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit bad in jquery. Am I doing right?

Should I just add the script which I have written below

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var arr = []
  $(":checkbox").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      arr.push($(this).val().toLowerCase())
    }
  })

  // removes duplicates
  var set = new Set(arr)

  // convert to array and join
  var vals = [...set].join(",")
  var str = "http://example.com/?subject=Products&checked=" + vals
  console.log(str);

  if (vals.length > 0) {
    $('.link').html($('<a>', {
      href: str,
      text: str
    }));
  } else {
    $('.link').html('');
  }
})
```

Am I right?

Or should I add any values on `var set = new Set(arr)` or `var vals = [...set]`

Thank you for you help **Algef**

Comment: It looks good! You should try this out and let us know if it worked.

Comment: @AlgefAlmocera It works and Thank you soo much... Just a Quick Issue, now the tag doesn't duplicate but when I Re-click the Checkbox the tag doesn't get removed....

I mean to say tag adds properly but when i click it doesn't get removed now....

Once again thank you Soo Much

Comment: Ah, I did see that bug even before any change was done. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: hey @AlgefAlmocera can you help me with any script in removing the tag When re-clicked?

Please ignore the Check 'Tick' which is not getting removed on reclick.

Comment: Thank you For you help @AlgefAlmocera